# How to prevent atd from running past jobs?

Tags: time, scheduling, daemon, at

The at daemon is a great tool! However, if a job is scheduled for 8:00 am and the machine is off at that time, at will run the job whenever the machine is booted. What I would like to do is stop it from running the job if the time is past. I have searched the man pages, and online, but either there is not an answer or I could not find one. I am using Arch, but as far as I know at is very similar across distributions.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When does a job become a past job? If you turn on the system at 7:59:50 and the `at` daemon starts at `8:00:01`, should the job be executed? What if the daemon starts at 7:59:59 but takes two seconds to read all of its files?

You decide! Start your job with a time check, and abort if the time is past.

```
export execute_by_date=$(date +%s 'tomorrow 8:01')
at tomorrow 8:00
[ "$(date +%s)" -le "$execute_by_date" ] || exit
do_stuff
␄
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an init-script that cancels all sheduled at-jobs on shutdown or reboot.

I am not sure about Arch-Linux - is there a `/etc/sysconfig/at` or something similar? Perhaps it is just a config-switch you have to flip over...

Comment: I think this is the best solution, flush the `at` queue at boot before `at` starts up.

Comment: This is exactly what I expect would/should be possible! Unfortunately there is no `/etc/sysconfig/` directory at all in Arch... And none of the files listed in the man pages are config files.

Comment: @Elmer I just Googled a bit and read about arch linux. '/etc/rc.d/atd' seems to be the init-script for the at-daemon there. Have a look there if you can see it parsing some config-file. If you are not lucky there you have to go for your own init-script (e.g name it `atclear` and run it before `atd`).

Answer (score 2):

My vote is for the `cron` daemon.

If you need to run it at specific times of the day, but not at the same time each day, I'd create a crontab with one entry per day range with an specific execution time:

Some examples taken from `crontab(5)`:

```
# run five minutes after midnight, every day
5 0 * * *       command
# run at 2:15pm on the first of every month
15 14 1 * *     command
# run at 10 pm on weekdays
0 22 * * 1-5    command
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the cron daemon. It does exactly what you want.

Feed you favourite search engine for *cron daemon* and you have a bunch of manuals and instructions. `man cron` and `man crontab` is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but cron does not work for my problem. I need a script run at specific times of the day, but not at the same time each day.